# OR instruction in assembly into ECX register

Tags: assembly, x86

in a book I'm reading, we are given the following snippet and problem:

> This function uses a combination SCAS and STOS to do its work. First,
>   explain what is the type of the [EBP+8] and [EBP+C] in line 1 and 8,
>   respectively. Next, explain what this snippet does:

```
01: 8B 7D 08    mov edi, [ebp+8]
02: 8B D7       mov edx, edi
03: 33 C0       xor eax, eax
04: 83 C9 FF    or ecx, 0FFFFFFFFh
05: F2 AE       repne scasb
06: 83 C1 02    add ecx, 2
07: F7 D9       neg ecx
08: 8A 45 0C    mov al, [ebp+0Ch]
09: 8B AA       mov edi, edx
10: F3 AA       rep stosb
11: 8B C2       mov eax, edx
```

I had nearly figured out everything after checking with an online solution (https://johannesbader.ch/2014/05/practical-reverse-engineering-exercises-page-11/), however, one step in this snippet still does not make sense ot me.

According to the online solution, when we run the command `or ecx, 0FFFFFFFFh` at **line 4**, it says

> We [now] interpret ECX as a signed integer -1

In order to know what the result is going to be for the `or` command, wouldn't we need to know previously what the value of `ECX` is? And why is the value -1?

Thanks

Comment: OR = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction , -1 = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: If it was an OR with literally anything else, then the previous value would have mattered.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I see now, thanks. I was aware of two's complement and had already been reading about it earlier. I just didn't realize any byte represented with all 1s would result in -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 32-bit [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of `-1` is `0xFFFFFFFF` (all-ones).   `1 OR x` is always `1`, so this unconditionally sets `ecx` to -1.  This trick only works for -1, because OR can only set bits, not clear them to zero.

---

The part of the solution that you quote, about interpreting "`ecx` as a signed integer -1", is only sensible in the context of the gdb command that follows:  `(gdb) p/d $ecx`  ->  `$7 = -1`.

**`rep` prefixes treat ecx as an unsigned counter**.  Setting ecx to -1 / UINT_MAX means [`repne scasb`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html) will only stop when it finds a zero in memory, not because `ecx` counted down all the way.  (In theory, if there was no zero, it would count down and end that way, but in practice it would segfault first.  `-1` isn't a special-case for `rep`).

---

#### Why use `or`: code size

The "normal" way to set a register to [anything other than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295) is with a 5 byte [`mov r32, imm32` insn](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html), for example  `B9 FF FF FF FF       mov    ecx,-1`.

If you care more about code-size than speed, or you know that a false dependency on `ecx` isn't a problem here, you can save two bytes by using a sign-extended 8-bit immediate: [`or r/m32, imm8`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/OR.html).

```
83 C9 FF    or ecx, 0FFFFFFFFh
```

None of the bits in the result actually depend on the old value of ecx, because.  However, real CPUs don't special-case this, so out-of-order execution can't get started until `ecx` is ready.  This is a **false dependency on the old value of ecx**.  `mov` breaks the dependency on the previous value.  (For more about this, see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, especially [Agner Fog's guides](http://www.agner.org/optimize/)).

`or ecx, imm8` needs a ModRM byte to encode the destination as ecx, unlike that form of `mov` where there's a separate opcode for each destination register.  There's unfortunately no opcode for `mov r/m32, imm8`, which would save 2 bytes of code in many instructions.

If Intel had been willing to drop [backwards compatibility with undocumented instructions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=25), they could have added it.  (8086 didn't have it, because it would only help 16-bit code when moving an immediate to memory.  They already dedicated 8 opcodes to `mov r16, imm16`, which is 3 bytes in 16-bit mode where it doesn't need an operand-size prefix, just like the non-existent `mov r/m16, imm8` would be.)

---

So **this is a useful idiom when optimizing for code-size**, e.g. for a bootloader, or a machine-code answer on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.  (Yes, that's a thing.)

**Another related trick is using a 3-byte `lea` to create a constant, if you already have another constant in another register.**  e.g. for [x86-64 Adler32, I needed two zeroed registers and a `1`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78896/compute-the-adler-32-checksum/78972#78972), so I used

```
401120:       31 c0          xor  eax,eax
401122:       99             cdq                 # zero rdx by sign-extending eax (0) into edx
401123:       8d 7a 01       lea  edi,[rdx+0x1]  # edi=0+1, using a reg + disp8 addressing mode
```

Comment: Peter, can you also write about how `add ecx, 2; neg ecx` works?  I mean I understand what it is doing, but how?  What "bit math" is lying under those instructions?  If that math exsits at all.  Thanks!

Comment: @RuslanGaripov: It's doing ecx = `-(ecx+2)` = `-ecx - 2`.  Before that, `ECX=(-1 - length)` (because of REP with that starting value), so it's doing ECX = `-(-1 - length) - 2` = `1+length - 2` = `length - 1`.  i.e. the string length not including the terminating 0, i.e. `strlen(edi)`.  IIRC,  it's common to use [a 2's complement identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278518/how-to-prove-that-the-c-statement-x-x1-and-x-1-yield-the-same-results) to save code-size, like `not ecx` / `dec ecx`, but it would be lower latency to use `mov -2, eax` / `sub eax,ecx` to return strlen).

Answer (score 2):

`F` in hex is `1111` in binary, so `0ffffffffh` is a DWORD with all bits set to `1`.
According to the truth table of `OR`, if you `OR` anything with `1`, you still get `1`.
So, no matter what `ECX` previously held, after this particular `OR` operation all of its bits will be set to `1`, which is `0ffffffffh`.  This is explained in the first link provided by Jose Manuel Abarca Rodriguez in a comment.

The Intel architecture (as well as most hardware architectures out there) use what is known as "two's complement representation" to establish a mapping between numbers and bit patterns in registers or in memory. In two's complement representation, `-1` is represented as `0ffffffffh`.  This is explained in the second link provided by Jose Manuel Abarca Rodriguez in a comment.