# What are the advantages of write-combine memory compared to write-back memory?

Tags: caching, x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, amd-processor

In *Software Optimization Guide for the AMD Zen4 Microarchitecture*, it is written that:

> Write-combining is the merging of multiple memory write cycles that target locations within the address range of a write buffer.

> To improve system performance, AMD Zen4 processors include a Write Combining Buffer (WCB) that consists of multiple 64-byte write buffers that are aligned to cache-line boundaries. The write buffers aggressively combine multiple memory-write cycles of any data size that address locations within 64-byte aligned regions. **The processor continues to combine writes to this buffer without writing the data to the system**, as long as certain rules apply (see Table 3 for more information). The data sizes can be bytes, words, doublewords, or quadwords.

However, for typical write-back memory, if the corresponding cacheline is valid in the cache, modifications will also occur within the cache and will not be directly written to the memory, which also **"buffers store operation without writing the data to the system"**.

Is there any fundamental difference between the mechanism of write-combine memory and write-back memory?

What are the direct performance advantages of write-combine? Why is it more efficient in some case?

Comment: See [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343231) and related stuff for more about no-RFO store protocols (which just invalidate instead).  That's the fundamental difference, that like NT stores to any memory type (except UC), ordinary stores to WC memory can avoid reading the old value of the line.  Full-line writes avoid a memory controller having to do an RMW or something.  Since NT stores evict the line from all caches, they're disastrous if you *are* going to read the line again soon on this core, and bad even for another core.

Comment: Assuming that AMD's write-combining buffers are at all similar to Intel's, [Does L1 cache accept new incoming requests while its Line Fill Buffers (LFBs) are fully exhausted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72201697) includes a performance experiment that intentionally fills them all up by doing multiple partial-line writes.  If AMD CPUs don't use the same buffers for tracking incoming lines, or for normal stores, then the title question for that Q&A is even more obviously no than for Intel, but perhaps a concrete example of a corner case might shed some light on how things behave.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much for your detailed answer. So whether it's storing to WC memory or using NT-store to WB memory, the only advantage is that it can reduce the implicit memory load operation caused by a write-allocation (for streaming data writes)?  Will there be any latency differences compared to regular storing operation?

Comment: Yes, there will be latency differences.  Did you read [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343231) like I recommended?  It talks about latency differences for Intel CPUs, especially Xeons.  As far as advantages, it's also guaranteed to flush to DRAM, which matters for persistent memory (NV-DIMM).  I don't know too much about mapping PCIe device memory as WC, how different that is from NT stores to DRAM.  I also don't know AMD details; some things could be different from Intel.