# About negate a sign-integer in mips?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, mips32

I'm thinking about how to negate a signed-integer in mips32. My intuition is using definition of 2's complement like: (suppose `$s0` is the number to be negated)

```
nor $t0, $s0, $s0   ; 1's complement
addiu $t0, $t0, 1   ; 2's = 1's + 1
```

then I realized that it can be done like:

```
sub $t0, $zero, $s0
```

so... what's the difference? Which is faster? IIRC sub will try to detect overflow, but would this make is slower? Finally, is there any other way to do so?

Comment: The `sub` variant is clearer; everyone knows that `0 - X == -X`, but not everyone knows that `~X+1 == -X` (and not everyone is familiar with the NOR operation). It's also as fast as you can possibly get, since it's a single instruction. The `nor` / `addiu` variant has a data hazard where `addiu` depends on the result of the `nor` instruction. In practice that will probably be handled without causing any pipeline stalls, but it depends on the specific MIPS implementation you're running on.

Comment: sub actually does the same thing but in a single ALU operation

Comment: @Michael: I also think `sub` is better, and it appears in the book I read. But I'm just curious/suspect that the underlying is doing the same thing as my first version...

Comment: @Minn: Cool, you answer my second comment in a second.

Comment: @Minn: But when you said that, I think I have the answer, right? `sub` is definitely faster! (assume that compiler didn't optimize it.)

Comment: In general, when it comes to mips a single instruction should always be faster than 2 instructions (not including things that cause flush or stalling)

Comment: The two variants are not equivalent. The `sub` will cause an exception on arithmetic overflow (i.e. when attempting to compute `-INT_MIN`). If you used `subu` (or `addi` rather than `addiu`) it would be equivalent.

Comment: That was mentioned in the question "IIRC sub will try to detect overflow", this was rather about whether its slower or faster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`subu $t0, $zero, $s0` is the best way, and is what compilers do.

On any given implementation of MIPS, most simple ALU instructions (add/sub/and/nor) have identical performance.  Getting the same work done in 1 simple instruction instead of 2 simple instructions is a win for code-size, latency, and throughput.

Fewer instructions isn't *always* better, but MIPS being a classic RISC ISA doesn't have many "slow" instructions other than mult / div / rem.

If you wanted `-x-1`, *then* you'd optimize that to a single `nor $t0, $zero, $s0` using [a 2's complement identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278518/how-to-prove-that-the-c-statement-x-x1-and-x-1-yield-the-same-results).

---

`sub` instead of `subu` would raise an exception on `-INT_MIN`, which you avoid using `addiu` in the nor/add version.  You should always use the `u` version of `sub` and `add` instructions unless you specifically *want* signed overflow to raise an exception.  C compilers always use the `u` version.  (In C, signed overflow is undefined behaviour<sup>1</sup>.)

```
int neg(int x) { return -x; }
```

[On the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:%27int+neg(int+x)+%7B+return+-x%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+foo(int+x)+%7B+return+-x-1%3B+%7D%0A%0Aunsigned+uabs(int+x)%7B%0A++++return+x%3C0+%3F+0U+-+x+:+x%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:28.4978569679307,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips1120,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-fno-delayed-branch%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27mips+gcc+11.2.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:29.879013202240746,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips1120,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dmips32r3+-fno-delayed-branch+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:11),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27mips+gcc+11.2.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:41.623129829828564,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), MIPS gcc11.2 `-O3 -fno-delayed-branch` compiles it exactly like we'd expect:

```
neg(int):
    subu    $2,$0,$4
    jr      $31
    nop              # filling the branch delay slot for
```

Asking a compiler is usually a good way to find efficient ways to do things in asm.  (GCC always makes asm that's compatible with real MIPS CPUs, and GAS is different from MARS/SPIM classic MIPS assembler.  See also [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052444/tweak-mips-gcc-output-to-work-with-mars))

---

> IIRC sub will try to detect overflow, but would this make is slower?

No.  In the no-exception case, `sub` has the same performance as `subu`, as far as I know on all MIPS CPUs.

CPUs are heavily optimized for the common case.  Taking an exception happens so rarely in normal code that it's fine for exceptions to take quite a lot of cycles.  So the CPU core just has to detect an exception before any bad result is written back to the register file, or stored to cache/memory.  There are at least a couple pipeline stages between Execute and Write-Back on any MIPS pipeline.

In the case of signed overflow, the ALU can produce the overflow signal in the same cycle as the result.  ISAs with a "flags" register that's updated by most instructions do this all the time as part of the normal operation of an `add` instruction: if software wants to do something special on signed overflow on x86 or ARM, they'd use a conditional branch on the overflow flag (OF on x86, V on ARM).  MIPS is special in that it's difficult to do anything other than take an exception on signed overflow.

---

**Footnote 1:** Undefined Behaviour means it's allowed to fault, but not *required* to fault, and often people would rather it didn't.  Compilers want to be able to optimize and introduce transformations that create temporary values that never exist in the C abstract machine, so they must avoid faulting when doing that.  Always using `subu` is a good way to do that, so it doesn't need to track whether the operation and the inputs values are ones that would have happened in the C abstract machine.  But in this case it would be legal to use `sub`.

Another implication of UB is that the compiler's allowed to assume that the `-x` result didn't overflow to `INT_MIN` and thus `x` before and after can't have been `INT_MIN`.

So if you were doing this as part of finding the absolute value, you'd want to avoid that with `0U - x` to convert `x` to unsigned before doing unsigned subtraction, producing an unsigned result. On a 2's complement machine like MIPS, casting signed int to same width unsigned is free, just use the bit-pattern unchanged.  `return x<0 ? 0U - x : x;`

For that, a 2's complement bithack *is* useful, which GCC uses with `-march=mips32r3` and later.  (IDK why it thinks branching is better on CPUs like `-march=r14000`, a 4-wide out-of-order exec CPU.)

```
uabs(int):
        sra     $3,$4,31          # broadcast the sign bit
        xor     $2,$4,$3          # ~x      or x
        subu    $2,$2,$3          # ~x-(-1) or x
        jr      $31
        nop
```