# how to change value at register in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

So currently at $t0 I have a variable x stored. I want $t0 to now store -x. How can I do this?

I tried

sub $t4, 0, $t0
move $t0, $t4

Any pointers as to why this says parser syntax error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568440/about-negate-a-sign-integer-in-mips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store -x in $t0 by using these 2 lines :

```
not $t0,$t0
addi $t0,$t0,1
```

These 2 lines basically apply 2's complement to the binary value stored in $t0.

**NOTE:** This might not be the most optimised choice in MIPS, but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

By the formula 0-x = -x , and knowing that `$0` is hard-coded to zero.

Try

```
sub $t0, $0, $t0
```

This will negate `$t0` and then put it back into `$t0`.