# MIPS Assembly: how to negate a register?

Tags: assembly, mips

[image: Screen-Shot-2022-05-29-at-2-14-09-PM.png]

In question iv.

Does my first instruction successfully negate the register i? Does my second instruction complete the problem?

Comment: Single-step it in a debugger (e.g. MARS) and try it yourself. Or read the same duplicate as your last question, [About negate a sign-integer in mips?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53568440), which already explains that this works.  I'm not sure why you think subtracting from zero might not work, or why you asked this after getting a link to that existing Q&A on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420074/mips-assembly-confused-with-negative-register).

Comment: `sub` will fault with integer overflow if `i = INT_MIN` since you use `sub` instead of `subu` and MIPS is a 2's complement machine, but in that case `1 - i` would also have faulted (signed overflow is undefined behaviour in C++).  So this is I think a fully valid implementation of that C snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works!

---

The use of `$t2` is unnecessary in this instruction sequence, as the first instruction can simply put the result directly back in `$t0`, since `$t0` is going to be updated anyway, and you need only `-i` after that point, but no longer need the original value of `i` itself.

Generally, it is good to reduce the number of registers used for small code sequences like this, since there are larger contexts in which we can run out of registers.

---

To me it would have been more natural to do:

```
li $t2, 1
sub $t0, $t2, $t0
```

Of course, that does require a 2nd register (no way to eliminate it), so to one measure, your code sequence (modified to use `$t0` only) is more optimal.

Comment: Indeed, `1 - i` is how compilers do it, since that has instruction-level parallelism while `(-1) + 1` doesn't.  The querent's previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420074/mips-assembly-confused-with-negative-register) already had a Godbolt link in comments showing `return -i` vs. `return 1-i`, and was closed as a duplicate of of [About negate a sign-integer in mips?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53568440) which also already explained that subtract-from-zero is correct for negation.  This seems like another near-exact duplicate; this question doesn't ask anything new.