# Two's complement representation of numbers

Tags: assembly, hex, x86-64, disassembly, twos-complement

The question is about the **Practice Problem 2.18** from the **Computer Systems: A Programmer Perspective** by Randal Bryant which states:

> For the lines labeled A–I (on the right) in the following listing, convert the hexadecimal values (**in 32-bit two’s-complement form**) shown to the right of the instruction names (sub, mov, and add) into their decimal equivalents (this is a disassembled program):

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `4004d0: 48 81 ec e0 02 00 00 sub $0x2e0,%rsp` | A | 736 |
| `4004d7: 48 8b 44 24 a8 mov -0x58(%rsp),%rax` | B | -88 |
| ... | ... | ... |

If I understand correctly from the problem **"shown to the right of the instruction names"** means these values - `0x2e0` and `-0x58`. But they don't seem to be in the two's complement form, they are just unsigned integers with the minus sign before them (probably I'm missing something).

What do I understand wrong here? Where are 32-bit hex values written in the two's complement form?

Comment: Do not post pictures of text!  I have downvoted your post and will retract my downvote once you change the picture into text.

Comment: Okay, I will remove the image, because it's not necessary here. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a weird question, yeah.  They're in little-endian 2's complement in the hexdump of the machine code, but showing you sign/magnitude human-readable hex in the disassembly kind of gives the game away: yes you just do hex->decimal conversion of the magnitude part, and keep the sign.

e.g. in the SUB instruction encoding:

```
48         81      ec     e0 02 00 00      sub  $0x2e0,%rsp

REX.W=1  opcode  modrm    imm32 (little-endian)
```

Or in the mov:

```
48       8b     44     24     a8                         mov  -0x58(%rsp),%rax
REX.W=1 opcode  ModRM  SIB   disp8 (signed 8-bit 2's complement)
```

The `a8` displacement sign-extends to 64-bit address-size as `0xffffffffffffffA8`; in CPU hardware the addressing mode is that plus RSP.

Or more easily to get a human-readable sign/magnitude representation, just do `0xa8 - 0x100 = -0x58` to range-shift / decode this 8-bit 2's complement bit-pattern that has its sign-bit set.

(Or of course take the 2's complement inverse to get the magnitude and remember that it was negative, e.g. `0x00 - 0xa8` with wrapping to 8-bit, or use the `-x = ~x+1` [identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278518/how-to-prove-that-the-c-statement-x-x1-and-x-1-yield-the-same-results) that for some reason many people prefer over one simple subtraction from zero.)